# search "htc sense" doesn't work?

Tags: search, bug, status-completed

I did a search on the words "htc sense" and only one article came up.  I started entering a question with the words HTC and sense in the title and several article were suggested with both words in the title. Is there a problem with search?

Comment: You can always use Google site search: `site:android.stackexchange.com htc sense`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, we do auto-convert search terms that match popular tags, into tags, if they are in the top (n) tags on a site.

This doesn't work so well for small sites though!

I added another sanity check so that we only do this auto-mapping when the # of questions in the tag is 200 or more.

So, this shouldn't be happening now.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the default search treats terms as tags.  "htc" would only find the htc tag.  "sense" would only find the sense tag.  htc-sense would be required to find htc-sense tag.

```
intitle:2 htc sense
```

Would be required to search for titles with "htc" and "sense".

Answer (score 0):

hmm, looks like the search doesn't pick up on the htc-sense tags, or the htc OR sense tags.  This would be a question for Jeff, you may want to cross post it to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: So, is search based only on tags?

Comment: @bcook no, we auto-map single words to popular tags -- because users kept doing really naive searches (e.g. "JAVA" on stack overflow) that were better expressed as tags

Answer (score 0):

Definitely something funny with search, I see no results searching for "google earth"

https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+earth

Even though there's a question with those words in that order in the title, a tag called google-earth, and I can remember seeing another couple of questions lately that reference Google Earth in the main question text.